# Appending Objects in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have just started using pandas and came across a problem when appending multiple objects into a single Pandas Series.
I know that you can create a large object first and then just call the pd.Series(**large object**)
However, I just wanted to know if it was possible to append multiple objects together. (Do we use DataFrame for this?)

```py
def foo():
    Points = pd.Series({})
    for i in range(len(df)):
        givenVal = {}
        givenVal[str(df.index[i])] = int(3*df.iloc[i]['somedata'])
        Points.append(pd.Series(givenVal)
    return(Points)
foo()
```

Thanks much for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Pandas Series allows you to add new items to the Series.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html#pandas.Series.add

Here are examples straight from the docs.

```
>>> a = pd.Series([1, 1, 1, np.nan], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
>>> a
a    1.0
b    1.0
c    1.0
d    NaN
dtype: float64
>>> b = pd.Series([1, np.nan, 1, np.nan], index=['a', 'b', 'd', 'e'])
>>> b
a    1.0
b    NaN
d    1.0
e    NaN
dtype: float64
>>> a.add(b, fill_value=0)
a    2.0
b    1.0
c    1.0
d    1.0
e    NaN
dtype: float64
```

After you've added all the elements you wanted you can finally Append the Series together.